# How does one run git-p4 in Windows?

Tags: windows, git, perforce, version-control

It doesn't look like git-p4 is part of the MSys-Git project for Windows.  Does anybody know how to get it running through Windows?

Comment: You're right, it's not supported by Git for Windows (also called MSysGit).  Feature request at https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/issues/108

Answer (score 18):

Update July 2019, the "[Git P4 clone broken](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46554774/6309)" question now mentions by [Gabriel Morin](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1077814/gabriel-morin):

```
[alias]
    p4 = !python.exe 'c:\\program files\\Git\\mingw64\\libexec\\git-core\\git-p4'
```

> Then using `git p4` from the command line worked.

---

With Git 2.32 (Q2 2021), `git p4` learned to find branch points more efficiently.

See [commit 6b79818](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6b79818bfbd39a5d41d15003375a9f382f70ad0e), [commit c3ab088](https://github.com/git/git/commit/c3ab08844c30f85342622fef1e4cf1ef1bb2bcd0) (05 May 2021) by [Joachim Kuebart (`jkuebart`)](https://github.com/jkuebart).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit e289f68](https://github.com/git/git/commit/e289f681ede1aad2ded33e76518bdc80064f3c16), 14 May 2021)</sup>

> ### [`git-p4`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6b79818bfbd39a5d41d15003375a9f382f70ad0e): speed up search for branch parent
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Joachim Kuebart</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: Junio C Hamano</sup>
> <sup>Helped-by: Luke Diamand</sup>

> For every new branch that `git-p4` imports, it needs to find the commit where it branched off its parent branch.
> While `p4` doesn't record this information explicitly, the first changelist on a branch is usually an identical copy of the parent branch.
>
> The method `searchParent()` tries to find a commit in the history of the given "parent" branch whose tree exactly matches the initial changelist of the new branch, "`target`".
> The code iterates through the parent commits and compares each of them to this initial changelist using `diff-tree`.
>
> Since we already know the tree object name we are looking for, spawning `diff-tree` for each commit is wasteful.
>
> Use the "`--format`" option of "`rev-list`" to find out the tree object name of each commit in the history, and find the tree whose name is exactly the same as the tree of the target commit to optimize this.
>
> This results in a considerable speed-up, at least on Windows.
> On one Windows machine with a fairly large repository of about 16000 commits in the parent branch, the current code takes over 7 minutes, while the new code only takes just over 10 seconds for the same changelist:
>
> Before:
>
> ```
> $ time git p4 sync
> Importing from/into multiple branches
> Depot paths: //depot
> Importing revision 31274 (100.0%)
> Updated branches: b1
>
> real    7m41.458s
> user    0m0.000s
> sys     0m0.077s
> ```
>
> After:
>
> ```
> $ time git p4 sync
> Importing from/into multiple branches
> Depot paths: //depot
> Importing revision 31274 (100.0%)
> Updated branches: b1
>
> real    0m10.235s
> user    0m0.000s
> sys     0m0.062s
> ```

---

Update March 2020

With Git 2.27 (Q2 2020), "`git p4`" is updated to work with Python 3.

See [commit 6bb40ed](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6bb40ed20a34a1c2f49efaef927afb63c4a81d41) (23 Jan 2020) by [SZEDER Gábor (`szeder`)](https://github.com/szeder).
See [commit 7575f4f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7575f4fdecf22cf232975625ec53add3f2b962e4), [commit ce425eb](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ce425eb4e16e5038ffc322cbafc80d641b0ad5eb), [commit 2e2aa8d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/2e2aa8d9032ccdfdecaab51c60c5bada517f60bc), [commit a6b1306](https://github.com/git/git/commit/a6b1306735f1a6450f22f562275c994d03324672), [commit 4294d74](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4294d741cc13e1f5533efaa693e4479c62b28873), [commit 50da1e7](https://github.com/git/git/commit/50da1e73933386ef95499d2f7753184ba82ce2b3), [commit 5a5577d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/5a5577d808668a7859c5009ddfa18b097368ba2c), [commit d38208a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d38208a297e76bbfbfa8e485632c217aaafa9486), [commit 86dca24](https://github.com/git/git/commit/86dca24b7be6491fb8d4b7a499ccf4a43776d1ab), [commit 6cec21a](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6cec21a82f437184c69cce2b8fe6011d02acfa06), [commit 1f8b46d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/1f8b46d0a4fdcb6fea566405cfc5422d39c36d52), [commit 0b4396f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/0b4396f0688f6c82ada83eab68b1c8dd3669d8bf) (13 Dec 2019) by [Yang Zhao (`yangminz`)](https://github.com/yangminz).
See [commit 484d09c](https://github.com/git/git/commit/484d09c303f271bdbdc2b7ed597e1d8f3959ce0f) (13 Dec 2019) by [Ben Keene (`seraphire`)](https://github.com/seraphire).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9a0fa17](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9a0fa1709c188d8be05aa573fa914d115f55aab1), 25 Mar 2020)</sup>

> ### [`ci`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6bb40ed20a34a1c2f49efaef927afb63c4a81d41): use python3 in linux-gcc and osx-gcc and python2 elsewhere
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: SZEDER Gábor</sup>

> Python2 reached end of life, and we have been preparing our Python scripts to work with Python3.

> '`git p4`', the main in-tree user of Python, has just received a number of compatibility updates.

This is documented only with Git 2.30 (Q1 2021) in [commit 263dc0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/263dc03b820d4b1f1fc3e2e70618124034f5cd2b).

---

Update July 2018:

Git 2.19 (Q3 2018) will start bringing Python 3 support to git p4.

See [commit db2d997](https://github.com/git/git/commit/db2d997efa43596fe5860d1b1c0c410e99d96f67), [commit f2606b1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f2606b1797fdffe40b00a6766ca1df6e1e0f3a60), [commit efdcc99](https://github.com/git/git/commit/efdcc99263871818cfe297a5a981d5841c77ebac), [commit 4d88519](https://github.com/git/git/commit/4d88519f6a2c7ea170f239a638137ce26d39cb11), [commit dba1c9d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/dba1c9d9f26ac9fce55d0bfde8a040700fc9ff52), [commit fc35c9d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/fc35c9d5dc8fefbc29e9713e6b47eb4c19579d56) (19 Jun 2018) by [Luke Diamand (`luked99`)](https://github.com/luked99).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 6dcd364](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6dcd36473a20e90d02463de5fe33eb94c4c33fa6), 18 Jul 2018)</sup>

> Code preparation to make "git p4" closer to be usable with Python 3.

---

Update January 2016:

Since 2010, [`contrib/fast-import/git-p4.README`](https://github.com/git/git/blob/8d530c4d64ffcc853889f7b385f554d53db375ed/contrib/fast-import/git-p4.README) mentions since April 2012

The git-p4 script moved to the top-level of the git source directory.
Note that the top-level git-p4.py script is now the source

> Windows users can copy the `git-p4.py` source script directly, possibly
> invoking it through a batch file called "`git-p4.bat`" in the same folder.
> It should contain just one line:

```
@python "%~d0%~p0git-p4.py" %*
```

(Although this [2013 article is invoking `git-p4.py` directly](http://jicui.github.io/git/2013/12/04/set-up-git-p4-in-window.html))

---

Original answer (April 2010)

As mention in "[Why Perforce is more scalable than Git](http://stevehanov.ca/blog/index.php?id=50)", be careful to not import in Git *any* p4 repo. Git cannot handle the same kind of huge unique repo P4 can manage.

Git-P4 being in Python, it should run on Windows (like in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1862944/git-p4-is-eating-my-image-files))

You can [grab git-p4.py here](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/git-p4.py) and use this as git-p4.bat

```
@python "%~d0%~p0git-p4" %*
```

It requires a Python 2.x installed.

Don't forget there is [another approach as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1594549/local-commits-pushing-to-a-central-server/1594595#1594595).

Comment: Installing Python 2.x and adding the `[alias]` section got me somewhere, but the command line for `git p4` does not seem to be well documented.  `git p4 clone //depot/mainline/...@all c:\path\to\git\clone` seems to have worked...

Comment: I also made a copy of the extensionless file `git-p4` as `git-p4.py` in the Git installation, but that was probably not necessary.

Comment: @Jake what version of Git are you using? The latest one would require python 3 for git p4 to better work.

Comment: "git version 2.36.1.windows.1" with Python 2.7.18, on Windows 10 Home 21H1 19043.1706.  Got all my revision history from Perforce into GitHub now, and looks good.

Answer (score 6):

The simplest answer I found, and seems to work flawlessly so far, was on [Timo Geusch's blog](http://www.lonecpluspluscoder.com/2013/06/how-to-enable-hack-git-p4-in-msysgit-for-windows/):

- Make sure you have Python 2.X installed, eg in `C:\Python27` (<strike>dunno if git-p4 supports Python 3, so I didn't risk it</strike> [git-p4.py does not support Python 3.X](https://github.com/msysgit/msysgit/issues/108), as of March 2014)
- Get a copy of git-p4.py from anywhere, eg as Eric Lathrop's blog post suggests, from the [git repo](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/git/git/master/git-p4.py) directly (I got mine from a linux install of git 2.1 that I happened to have already set up)
- In your MSysGit installation, navigate to `libexec\git-core`, eg on my Git for Windows 1.9.4-preview20140611 install on windows 7 64-bit that is `C:\Program Files (x86)\Git\libexec\git-core`
- Drop your git-p4.py file there
- At that same location, edit the "git-p4" extensionless file, replacing the dummy echo and exit lines with a single line

  c:/python27/python "c:/program files (x86)/Git/libexec/git-core/git-p4.py" $1 $2 $3 $4 $5 $6 $7 $8 $9

That's it. git-p4 now works on your MSysGit / Git for Windows installation just like it does on any linux box.

(please note, [Eric Lathrop's existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18727142/74296) has a lot of additional information about working with git-p4 and all its limitations; I thought this question could benefit from a simple howto answer to the actual question though, i.e. easily getting it working on Windows, lest more wanderers be discouraged as I was last week)

Comment: Note that if python is in your PATH, you can drop git-p4.py directly on top of the dummy libexec/git-core/git-p4.

Comment: Python3 comes with a script _2to3.py_ (in directory Tools/Scripts) that can be used to convert scripts written for Python2 to script that run with Python3, but I have not tested if it works for _git-p4.py_. The command for the conversion would be: `python 2to3.py -w git-p4.py` (assuming that both _2to3.py_ and _git-p4.py_ are in the current directory).

Answer (score 5):

I got it to work, but it was a long, arduous process, fraught with peril. I wrote up the instructions on my blog: http://ericlathrop.com/2012/12/how-to-set-up-git-p4-in-windows/

Comment: Thanks for posting your answer! Please note that you should post the essential parts of the answer here, on this site, or your post risks being deleted [See the FAQ where it mentions answers that are 'barely more than a link'.](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#deletion) You may still include the link if you wish, but only as a 'reference'. The answer should stand on its own without needing the link.

Comment: Note that you don't need an old version of msysgit; see Tao's answer below.

Comment: The linked URL does not load.  Shame the details were not posted here instead.  Downvoted and suggest removal of this answer.

Answer (score 1):

After reading https://git-scm.com/docs/git-p4

```
 py -2 "C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\libexec\git-core\git-p4" clone //Projects/App/@all
```

Worked for me

Comment: That is possibly all the `git` command line does, but it would be nicer to have it set up to use the documented CLI.